# Where can I find virtual switches to learn about layer 2

Tags: switch, layer2

I am learning about layer 2 networking, arp, cam tables, mac addresses etc. I will like to see some of these things in action but I do not have access to physical hardware now, does anyone know of a virtual software I can use? I know there are virtualised implementation of certain network functionality, for example https://frrouting.org/ for routing, but I am not interested in routing now, but just switching. So anyone knows something like frrouting but for switching, where I can run which will have virtual ports, and I can connect processes to these virtual ports?

Comment: There are a few network simulators that also cover switches, they should get you started. Product recommendations are off-topic here however but you could try on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Since simulation is limited, I'd recommend obtaining a managed switch.

Comment: What do you mean by managed swtich? Can you share examples?

Comment: A managed switch can be configured and looked into, see [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43568/can-a-switch-that-does-not-support-vlan-capability-be-considered-a-managed-switc) for more details. [This question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/osi-model-and-networking-protocols-relationship) provides a general overview and then - just search and browse here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two open source virtual switch platforms:
[OpenVSwitch](https://www.openvswitch.org/) and [OpenSwitch](https://www.openswitch.net/) (which is a Linux foundation project). Check them out.